# Android Spinner bigger at runtime

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hello guys I'm new to android, Why is my spinner bigger at **runtime** than in design? How can I fix this
thanks in advance....

Here is the screen capture[image]

Comment: why have you put radio button into spinner?

Comment: post the layout xml file that you have used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  month);
       NoCoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     mon_spinner.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
```

Please try this coding. It works better for me and it will help you.

Comment: I tried replacing "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item" with
"android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item"
and removed the setDropdownViewresource

How come it still big when i did that?

Comment: If you added setdropdownresource is worked well or not. Then why do you removed this?

Comment: Well I just tried it out. Just want to see the difference
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can set height

```
android:layout_height="40dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="20dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Spinner or any thing you need constant size means you need to set
>   the android:layout_width and android:layout_height as constant
>   according to your requirement.

```
android:layout_width  = "U r required size dp"

android:layout_height = "U r required size dp"
```